# How to get more detailed profiling data when firebase realtime db is at 100% usage for a long time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We're having problems with the realtime database so we decided to use the profiler for this with the `--raw` and `--duration` option. It works great in some cases if the usage is just around 70-90%. But when it hits 100% and stays for minutes (~15mins max). The profiler will stop accepting data or no data has been recorded.

We are full aware that it could be on how we call or listens to firebase node. But we would love to know what paths are they so we know where to begin with. The GCP monitoring however records how many listens happened on that timeframe but there's no detailed path or whatsoever that can help us.

Is there any other options we can do to get the data when it hit 100% or just method that we can use to at least know what is happening in the current timeframe?

Comment: It sounds like you're either reading a large part of (or the entire) database at that point, or you're performing a large operation. While the database is serving that request, it won't handling any other requests (nor logging profile information, because it's busy with just that one request). I'm actually not sure how to determine the path of the operation in that case, so am hoping someone else can chime in.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, is that even possible, that we can read the entire database? I thought only the top childs. We have several childs on the root. If you're right then that is really a problem we need to address. Butdo you think the high `listen` usage can only point to one single path that is busy waiting and not the accumulation of multiple calls?

Comment: I'd expect the profiler to show the individual paths if there are multiple calls.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes but not when its hitting 100%